# Ngrok Teams Issue

Tags: npm, microsoft-teams, ngrok, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to complete the following Tutorial, that teaches you how to build personal tabs in teams:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-oJ55vuwEk&list=PLWZJrkeLOrbY8HkTBBvyx-uyZ3cCdl1VM&index=3

As I type gulp ngrok-serve and try to serve the application, the webpage loads, saying
"Before you can serve HTML content, you must sign up for a free ngrok account and install your authtoken."
I already have registered a config auth token.
What else should I do? Any help is very much appreciated.

I reinstalled ngrock both using brew and downloading it from the website, I reinstalled the auth tokens an infinite number of times..

Comment: you can try run ngrok manually from the command line, and then run the application separately too (should be gulp serve)

Comment: When I only use Gulp-serve, the personal tab is displayed as expected with localhost. When I use ngrok, no.. This makes things difficult because I can't load the app in Teams.